# UI Automation "could not be tapped because the element is not visible" iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, automation, automated-tests

this is driving me insane, if anyone can help I'd really appreciate it...
I'm trying to write a ui automation script to test an app. There is a particular collection view, where the cells are generated from a nib via firstly the view did load....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = @"Forms";

    [self.categoryCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HomeCategoryCell"    bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeCategoryCell"];
    [self.formsCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HomeFormCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeFormCell"];
    [self.existingFormsCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HomeExistingFormCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeExistingFormCell"];

    [self setupFormCategories];
}
```

And then a setup form method...

```
- (void)setupFormCategories
{
    categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    FormCategory *cat = [[FormCategory alloc] init];
    cat.categoryTitle = @"All Forms";
    cat.iconFileName = @"CategoryIcon.png";
    cat.relatedForms = @[@"Form Type 1", @"Form Type 2"];
    [categories addObject:cat];

    cat = [[FormCategory alloc] init];
    cat.categoryTitle = @"Customer Forms";
    cat.iconFileName = @"CategoryIcon.png";
    cat.relatedForms = @[@"Form Type 1", @"Form Type 2"];
    [categories addObject:cat];

    cat = [[FormCategory alloc] init];
    cat.categoryTitle = @"Client Forms";
    cat.iconFileName = @"CategoryIcon.png";
    cat.relatedForms = @[@"Form Type 1", @"Form Type 2"];
    [categories addObject:cat];

    cat = [[FormCategory alloc] init];
    cat.categoryTitle = @"User Forms";
    cat.iconFileName = @"CategoryIcon.png";
    cat.relatedForms = @[@"Form Type 1", @"Form Type 2"];
    [categories addObject:cat];

    brandNewForms = nil;
}
```

I have tried several ways of selecting one of these forms, (both the categoryTitle and then the related forms...

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()["User Forms"].tap();
```

As well as firstWithPredicate etc... However I always get the same response....

Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()["User Forms"] could not be tapped because the element is not visible on line 64 of wip.js

If I log the element tree, it can see all of the element types and returns a full element tree. If I record user interaction via Instruments, it recognises the elements, and will generate this javascript...

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()["User Forms"].tap();
```

No matter what I do I can't get it to work. I've tried changing the accessibility settings via interface builder, ensuring the view it is a sub of does not have any accessibility set, however I can't get it to work. I also can't understand why it would recognise the elements in logElementTree and record, but not when run...

Any ideas... Any suggestions how I may be able to modify the objective C code if this is the problem....? I've tried playing with the cat.accessibilityLabel= @"User Forms"; but I'm a newbie to objective C and I don't really know what I'm doing....

xCode 5 / iOS7 simulator... but I've also tried in xCode 4.6.3 / iOS6.1....

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, it sounds like the cell you want to tap is in the view hierarchy, but its literally just not visible on the screen.

Maybe you have to scroll first to make it visible.  Also, it looks like you have different categories of items.  Maybe you have to select the right category in your app before that cell is visible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. They're all displayed horizontally at the top of the screen. I don't think scrolling to it will help, also it won't let me select either the top category or the sub category (I've tested by tapping co-orindates but it won't let me select any of the categories, it says they're all not visible....

Comment: Maybe something in your view takes some time to load.  Try adding a delay in your script before the problematic tap and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Hi, I just tried that again, adding a 20 second delay. It still doesn't work, I didn't think that was the issue anyway, because I do a Tune_JS assert check to make sure the elements are all there just before that, and that passes, for some reason though when I ask the script to tap on one of them it says they're not visible.... I'm stumped....